# I have an unknown device connected to my wifi and the only info it gives me is this mac adress f2:9c:10:eb:24:0b and i dont get any hitslooking it up

Tags: mac-address

This mac adress is the only information I can get off of this unknown device connected to my wifi.Ive look up this mac adress and its not linked to any device. Can someone please help figure out what or who is connected to my wifi

Comment: Look up the connection with Advanced IP Scanner (Famatech).  It may be an old device around your residence.  One similar case recently was a digital picture frame.

Comment: I am not sure what the question is, we can't help you identify the device, I assume the device is currently assigned an IP address?  If you can't identify the device, start unplugging any device, that might be the device in question until it's disconnected.

Comment: It could also be an attacker connected to your network who has spoofed his mac address. Try to log into your router, and check what devices are connected to your network, and if you can identify them.

Comment: Where did you see this MAC address? In your router’s web interface? Or maybe in your PCs Network neighborhood?

Comment: Did it actually connect and get an IP address? If not it may be a phone looking for nearby networks. More information [here](https://appuals.com/fix-unknown-strange-devices-showing-network/).

Answer (score 2):

Just change your wifi SSid and password and reconnect your devices to the wifi,

the unknown device will be disconnected automatically.
It might just be a neighbour Who once came to your house and connected to your wifi once, and now his phone automatically connects to your wifi without his knowledge.

it might be a smart device that you have forgotten about. all of then have a IP address

Anyway, you can manually go to each device and write down their mac addresses. Since they never change it will be a good list to have.

Answer (score 2):

It is one Apple iOS device that has private address enabled on the wifi connection.
It then spoof an MAC address that starts with F2:9C:F8, non existent company prefix in the MAC register

Turn off private address when connection to your home network, and you will see the real mac address of the  iOS device

https://mac.lc/address/F2:9C:F8